# Spotify API getting current user's data returning error unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

Currently trying to get current logged in user's data, but anything I request with `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me` is giving me `401 Unauthorized` errors. Using `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{id}` works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

```
app.get('/playlist', function(req, res) {
var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
        code: access_code,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
    },
    json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        var token = body.access_token;

        var options = {
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            json: true
        };

        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                res.send(body);
            } else {
                console.log('Error retrieving playlists');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Error authenticating playlist: ' + response.statusCode);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Are you sure the first call does not return any error?

If you try to `console.log(token)` does it give to you a token?

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{id}` works because it does not require any authorization

Comment: Related: maybe you need to do `body = JSON.parse(body)`?

Comment: @rpadovani yes it returns a token. The error it gives me is `Error retrieving playlists`. Error is null, body is undefined and response.statusCode is 401.